# What browsers does the Java Deployment Toolkit support?

Tags: java, deployment

I have been unable to find a list of supported browsers for the [Java Deployment Toolkit](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/depltoolkit_index.html). Does anyone know of such a list?

If not, can anyone provide experience of what browsers they have successfully used it with. I want to confirm that Internet Explorer 6 is supported.

Comment: I couldnt find any information either, but good question though! +1
Reading through the JavaScript (http://java.com/js/deployJava.js) I couldnt find anything indicating that it does not work with IE6. Maybe somebody may try a simple example and tell us the solution.

Comment: I had a look through the JavaScript myself and came to the same conclusion but you would think there would be a compatibility list somewhere.

Comment: "Chrome, Safari, and Opera browsers find the plugin but it doesn't work, so until we can get it to work - don't use it." http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.txt

Comment: @trashgod Thanks for that. For the environments our application would be deployed in we probably only need to worry about IE and Firefox support.

Comment: @trashgod  I do not quite understand the quote.  After following the link & searching on 'chrome' FF turned up 3 references, none of which were that quoted sentence.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: Yes, the comment now just mentions [Safari and Opera](http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.txt).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like IE, Netscape & Safari.
http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.txt

```
getJREs: function() {
    var list = new Array();
    if (deployJava.isPluginInstalled()) {
        var plugin =  deployJava.getPlugin();
        var VMs = plugin.jvms;
        for (var i = 0; i < VMs.getLength(); i++) {
            list[i] = VMs.get(i).version;
        }
    } else {
        var browser = deployJava.getBrowser();

        if (browser == 'MSIE') {
            if (deployJava.testUsingActiveX('1.7.0')) {
                list[0] = '1.7.0';
            } else if (deployJava.testUsingActiveX('1.6.0')) {
                list[0] = '1.6.0';
            } else if (deployJava.testUsingActiveX('1.5.0')) {
                list[0] = '1.5.0';
            } else if (deployJava.testUsingActiveX('1.4.2')) {
                list[0] = '1.4.2';
            } else if (deployJava.testForMSVM()) {
                list[0] = '1.1';
            }
        } else if (browser == 'Netscape Family') {
            deployJava.getJPIVersionUsingMimeType();
            if (deployJava.firefoxJavaVersion != null) {
                list[0] = deployJava.firefoxJavaVersion;
            } else if (deployJava.testUsingMimeTypes('1.7')) {
                list[0] = '1.7.0'; 
            } else if (deployJava.testUsingMimeTypes('1.6')) {
                list[0] = '1.6.0';
            } else if (deployJava.testUsingMimeTypes('1.5')) {
                list[0] = '1.5.0';
            } else if (deployJava.testUsingMimeTypes('1.4.2')) {
                list[0] = '1.4.2';
            } else if (deployJava.browserName2 == 'Safari') {
                if (deployJava.testUsingPluginsArray('1.7.0')) {
                    list[0] = '1.7.0'; 
                } else if (deployJava.testUsingPluginsArray('1.6')) {
                    list[0] = '1.6.0';
                } else if (deployJava.testUsingPluginsArray('1.5')) {
                    list[0] = '1.5.0';
                } else if (deployJava.testUsingPluginsArray('1.4.2')) {
                    list[0] = '1.4.2';
                }
            }
        }
    }
```